# Running a background task in rails that never closes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on trying to integrate some slack commands that can interact with my Rails application. Awhile back, I was leveraging Sidekiq for this, but then I realized that this might not be a good idea.

I'm using the following Gems to accomplish this currently:

```
# Slack-ruby-client
gem "eventmachine"
gem "async-websocket", "~> 0.8.0"
gem "rails_best_practices"
gem "slack-ruby-client"
gem "websocket-driver"
```

When the worker would usually execute, it would run the following:

```
  def monitor
    @client.on :hello do
      @messenger.send_message("Bot is now connected!")
    end

    @client.on :message do |data|
      case data.text
      when /!help/
          ... etc
```

However, I feel like this isn't a good practice. From time to time, the worker would run twice (if it's been running for a few days, it may restart itself for some reason). Is there a better way to do this in Rails?

Comment: If you need a long running process that responds to incoming requests, `rails server` rather fits that description. Could you not use something like the [Slack Events API over HTTP](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api) and play to Rails' strengths?

Comment: Interesting. Haven't heard of this before so I'll definitely look into this. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: It's not really a good idea to bundle up a neverending background job in your webserver, because you may need to deploy multiple webservers as you scale, and then you'll have multiple listeners. Even if you have only a single webserver, your listeners would have downtime every time you deploy. It's better to deploy the listener as its own microservice